# Bluemail notification sound - Permissions under snap folder

Tags: permissions, snap, root, ownership

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so I'll try to explain the best I can.
I want to change the sound notification of my Bluemail snap app but there are no options in the settings, so I tried to change the audio file, but the mp3 files are in "/snap/bluemail/144/resources/resources/audio", not in "/home/user/..."
Everything under this snap folder is owned by root, but I cannot open the folder as root. No way to replace or even rename the files.
Is there something I can do, am I missing something ?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Snaps are read-only mounts ("loop mounts" of sandboxed static compiled code and files).  Even as `root` you can't change the contents of any files under the snap in its mount points.

If you intend to customize the configuration of an application, you should not be using the snap version of a given application because you won't be able to revise anything inside the snap.